# Can I load a function from the came controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, function

I have this basic function a controller:

```
public function index(){
  if($this->input->ip_address() == XX.XX.XXX.XXX){
    $this->status(1);
  }
}
protected function status($status_no){
    echo $status_no;
}
```

But the status function does nothing. It doesn't even load.  I can confirm my IP is correct and my IF statement & controller index is okay.

I will be looking forward to some help.

Peter

Comment: your code should work, try calling the method outside the IF statement, i just tested this in a fresh CI installation

Comment: @Maluchi post that as an answer, my if statement was wrong!

Comment: If oyu post it as an answer I'll select it as an answer. I shouldn't drink when coding aha!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should work, try calling the method outside the IF statement, i just tested this in a fresh CI installation